# Accessing key-value pairs of Java Map in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, dictionary

I have a `Map<String, String>` in back-end which is sent to front-end javascript as Map. I need to get all key-value pairs and display it in UI. For doing this, I have tried like,

```
org.JSON.JSONObject js = new org.JSON.JSONObject(Map);
```

But it does not work. Is there any way to handle Java map in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like using ObjectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;),

```
  String jsString =  new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Map<String,String>)
```

Then you can create jsonObject as,

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(jsString);
```